# Is it possible to convert string into float when importing a csv file into mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

He.llo, folks

I'm studying SQL and as a practical exercise i'm trying to import a .csv file from my country's governemnt database.

Basically it's a file that contains 4 rows:
Date, coin name, value, qnty and **these rows aren't formatted as I need it to be**.

Date is ok, it is YYYY-MM-DD

Coin name is ok too, because its a string

And value (coin value, like 0.1 or 10) is ok too because of its formatted with dots only

**The problem comes with qnty.**
Quantity is how much coins/notes are available for citizens, but it is formatted with dots and commas (this is the real problem I can't figure out)

Take this example:

1995-01-02;Moedas - 1a. Família (inox);0.01;834.342.314,00

1995-01-02;Moedas - 1a. Família (inox);0.05;636.711.876,00

1995-01-02;Moedas - 1a. Família (inox);0.10;583.076.666,00

1995-01-02;Moedas - 1a. Família (inox);0.25;146.883.388,00

1995-01-02;Moedas - 1a. Família (inox);0.50;329.791.540,00

Is there someway to convert qnty (e.g: 329.791.540,00) into float?

Thank you!

----- edit 01:17 GMT
I applied REPLACE as **Marco** said to the whole table

```
SELECT data_,nome,valor,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(qntd,'.',''),',','.') AS FLOAT) AS qntd    
FROM indata;
```

Is this correct? But even if it is correct, didnt work, the values were
5.890.789.013,00 -> 5890790000
It looks like it was rounded up

-------- EDIT 01:39 GMT
When I changed FLOAT -> DOUBLE it worked, anybody knows why?

Note that records on qnty field can be up to billions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE()` string function, twice; once to replace the dots with nothing, once to replace the decimal comma with a dot, and cast that expression to float - like in this small demo example using your first literal in that format:

```
WITH indata(s) AS (
  SELECT '834.342.314,00' FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(s,'.',''),',','.') AS FLOAT) AS f 
FROM indata;
-- out      f     
-- out -----------
-- out  834342314
```

Comment: Thks Marco, but it didn't work for me. The values were rounded up, I have no idea why. I modified your code to apply to the whole table (I edited my question showing this) but even if i havent modified, it wouldnt work. I tried using only what you suggested and it returned -> 834342000 not 834342314 as expected

Comment: Strangely when I changed FLOAT -> DOUBLE it worked, do you know why?

Comment: double is a float with double precision, so it's to expected that the it does not have the same coarseness in the precision. You could also consider number(18,4) instead of double, to have a reliable rounding precision throughout

Comment: Good to know! I'm a beginner so I may have dumb doubts, but you clarified my question! Thanks, Marco, it worked as expected, as well as Albert anwser's. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
    data_,
    nome,
    valor,
    CAST( REPLACE ( REPLACE ( qntd, '.', '' ), ',', '.' ) AS DECIMAL ( 12, 2 ) ) AS qntd 
FROM
    indata;
```